# Sumproduct of arrays using lookups between tables

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerbi, dax, powerquery

**Using O365**

[image: Start]

In F2, find sum for Type "Revenue" and Group "A" using the Amount & Allocation % Tables.

F2 = $10,000 * 10 % + $15,000 * 20% = $4,000

10% = ACCT + A

20% = BRRT + A

I'm trying to avoid adding helper columns to the Amount Table such as:

[image: Solution1NotPreferred]

Using `=XLOOKUP(Table1[@[Dept]:[Dept]]&Table1[[#Headers],[A]],Table2[[Dept]:[Dept]]&Table2[[Group]:[Group]],Table2[[Alloc%]:[Alloc%]],0)*Table1[@[Amount]:[Amount]]`

So far, I am stumped about how to proceed without the use of Helper Columns and a SUMIFS in J2. This method would use too many resources given my dataset size (200k rows).

Any ideas? SUMPRODUCT with SUMIFS? Power BI table links and DAX? TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are on the right tract with SUMPRODUCT and SUMIFS:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(Table1[[Amount]:[Amount]],Table1[[Type]:[Type]],Table4[@[Type]:[Type]],Table1[[Dept]:[Dept]],Table2[[Dept]:[Dept]])*Table2[[Alloc %]:[Alloc %]]*(Table2[[Group]:[Group]]=Table4[[#Headers],[A]]))
```

- Table1 = A1:C5
- Table2 = A7:15
- Table4 = E1:I3

[image]

Comment: Scott - thank you! I knew it was something simple with those two functions. I also just realized I can Merge Table1 and Table2 + add a Custom Column for Amount*Alloc% to make myself a flat table to read from :) cheers